# plotting 3D playes in R, anyone can look through the code

Tags: r, shiny

I hope anyone can help me :)
 Write this code including shiny, but at the end it doesnt work the way I want it to.
If anyone can look through that code an tell me why the plot isnt working ?
You will see that there is an error at the end.

Ok first why istn the rgl window implemented into the GUI ?
Second how can I plot the 3D in bigger cube ?
If I dont open a 3D plot wihtout data it doesnt plot it at all :(

```
library(shiny)
library(rgl)
library(shinythemes)
library(devtools)
#install_github("rgl", "trestletech", "js-class")
#install_github("rgl", "trestletech", "js-class")

#######################################################################################
#                                   User Interface                                    #
#######################################################################################



ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("slate"),

#shinythemes::themeSelector(),  # <--- Add this somewhere in the UI

  headerPanel("Block Theory 0.1"),

  sidebarPanel(

     numericInput(inputId = "dd", label = "Dip direction:", value = "", width = "80%", min = 0, max = 360),

     numericInput(inputId = "fa", label = "Fracture angle:", value = "", width = "80%", min = 0, max = 90),

     numericInput(inputId = "position_x", label = "Position:", value = "", width = "40%"),

     numericInput(inputId = "position_y", label = "", value = "", width = "40%"),

     selectInput("form", "Form:",
                 c("Circle", "Square", "Ellipsoid")),

     actionButton(inputId = "add", label = "Add a plane"),

     actionButton(inputId = "plotbutton", label = "Update")

  ),

  mainPanel(  

    plotOutput(outputId = "plot")
  ),


verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "log_planes")


)


#######################################################################################
#                                       SERVER                                        #
#######################################################################################


server <- function(input, output) {

data_planes <- data.frame()
makeReactiveBinding("data_planes")  



observe({
    input$add
    isolate({
      data_planes <<- rbind(data_planes, data.frame(input$dd, input$fa , input$position_x , input$position_y))
      data_planes <<- na.omit(data_planes)

       })
  })  


output$plot <- renderRglwidget({

 # try(rgl.close())

  input$plotbutton

     isolate({

#######################################################################################     
#    Open 3d plot:

     x<-sample(1:100, 100)
     y<-sample(1:100, 100)
     z<-sample(1:100, 100)
     plot3d(x, y, z, type = "n",xlim = c(-10, 10), ylim = c(-10, 10), zlim = c(-30, 30))

####################################################################################### 

      while (i <= nrow(data_planes)) {

        phi <- data_planes[i,1] * pi / 180
        deta <- data_planes[i,2] * pi / 180
        Px <- data_planes[i,3]
        Py <- data_planes[i,4]
        Pz <- 0
        n <- c(-sin(deta)*sin(phi), sin(deta) * cos(phi), -cos(deta))

        T <- matrix(c(cos(deta)*cos(phi), sin(deta), cos(deta)*sin(phi), -sin(deta)*cos(phi), cos(deta), -sin(deta)*sin(phi), -sin(phi), 0 , cos(phi)), nrow=3,ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

        P_new <- T %*% c(Px,Py,Pz)

        P_n <- -P_new %*% n      # d = -P * n

# planes3d() plots equation:   a*x + b*y +  c*z + d = 0         

        a <- -sin(deta)*sin(phi)
        b <- sin(deta) * cos(phi)
        c <- -cos(deta)
        d <- P_n          


        cols<-rgb(runif(5),runif(5),runif(5))  #random color genarator

        planes3d(a, b, c , d , col = cols, alpha = 1.0)


        i <- i + 1       
      }
    })
  })

output$log_planes <- renderPrint({na.omit(data_planes)})



}
#######################################################################################
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few mistakes in your app:

Firstly, in your `ui` instead of `plotOutput(outputId = "plot")` it should be `rglwidgetOutput(outputId = "plot")`.

Secondly, you wont be able to plot in a loop and also you need to give `rglwidget()`. Just for demonstration purpose I have altered your server code by removing the loop. Have a look:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  data_planes <- data.frame()
  makeReactiveBinding("data_planes")  



  observe({
    input$add
    isolate({
      data_planes <<- rbind(data_planes, data.frame(input$dd, input$fa , input$position_x , input$position_y))
      data_planes <<- na.omit(data_planes)

    })
  })  


  output$plot <- renderRglwidget({

    # try(rgl.close())

    input$plotbutton

    # isolate({

      #######################################################################################     
      #    Open 3d plot:

      x<-sample(1:100, 100)
      y<-sample(1:100, 100)
      z<-sample(1:100, 100)
      plot3d(x, y, z, type = "n",xlim = c(-10, 10), ylim = c(-10, 10), zlim = c(-30, 30))

      ####################################################################################### 
      i=1;
      # while (i <= nrow(data_planes)) {

        phi <- data_planes[i,1] * pi / 180
        deta <- data_planes[i,2] * pi / 180
        Px <- data_planes[i,3]
        Py <- data_planes[i,4]
        Pz <- 0
        n <- c(-sin(deta)*sin(phi), sin(deta) * cos(phi), -cos(deta))

        T <- matrix(c(cos(deta)*cos(phi), sin(deta), cos(deta)*sin(phi), -sin(deta)*cos(phi), cos(deta), -sin(deta)*sin(phi), -sin(phi), 0 , cos(phi)), nrow=3,ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

        P_new <- T %*% c(Px,Py,Pz)

        P_n <- -P_new %*% n      # d = -P * n

        # planes3d() plots equation:   a*x + b*y +  c*z + d = 0         

        a <- -sin(deta)*sin(phi)
        b <- sin(deta) * cos(phi)
        c <- -cos(deta)
        d <- P_n          


        cols<-rgb(runif(5),runif(5),runif(5))  #random color genarator

        i <- i + 1



      # }

      planes3d(a, b, c , d , col = cols, alpha = 1.0)

      rglwidget()
    # })
  })

  output$log_planes <- renderPrint({na.omit(data_planes)})



}
```

The output you see from this code is:[image]

**EDIT:**

To plot more than 1 plot at a time and adjust the x, y and z limits you can use this server code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  data_planes <- data.frame()
  makeReactiveBinding("data_planes")  



  observe({
    input$add
    isolate({
      data_planes <<- rbind(data_planes, data.frame(input$dd, input$fa , input$position_x , input$position_y))
      data_planes <<- na.omit(data_planes)

    })
  })  


  output$plot <- renderRglwidget({

    # try(rgl.close())

    input$plotbutton

    # isolate({

      #######################################################################################     
      #    Open 3d plot:

      x<-sample(1:100, 100)
      y<-sample(1:100, 100)
      z<-sample(1:100, 100)
      plot3d(x, y, z, type = "n",xlim = c(min(x), max(x)), ylim = c(min(y), max(y)), zlim = c(min(z), max(z)))
       #################################################### 
      i=1;
       while (i <= nrow(data_planes)) {

        phi <- data_planes[i,1] * pi / 180
        deta <- data_planes[i,2] * pi / 180
        Px <- data_planes[i,3]
        Py <- data_planes[i,4]
        Pz <- 0
        n <- c(-sin(deta)*sin(phi), sin(deta) * cos(phi), -cos(deta))

        T <- matrix(c(cos(deta)*cos(phi), sin(deta), cos(deta)*sin(phi), -sin(deta)*cos(phi), cos(deta), -sin(deta)*sin(phi), -sin(phi), 0 , cos(phi)), nrow=3,ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

        P_new <- T %*% c(Px,Py,Pz)

        P_n <- -P_new %*% n      # d = -P * n

        # planes3d() plots equation:   a*x + b*y +  c*z + d = 0         

        a <- -sin(deta)*sin(phi)
        b <- sin(deta) * cos(phi)
        c <- -cos(deta)
        d <- P_n          


        cols<-rgb(runif(5),runif(5),runif(5))  #random color genarator

        i <- i + 1

        planes3d(a, b, c , d , col = cols, alpha = 1.0) 

       }

      rglwidget()
    # })
  })

  output$log_planes <- renderPrint({na.omit(data_planes)})



}
```

Comment: Wow thanks alot :) But now its the question, when I cant plot in a loop, what other way can I go to plot more than 1 plane at a time ?

And also you see I open a 3d windows with + - 10, how can I make that window dynamic so if the plane will be larger that it will not get cut off ?

:)

Comment: Thx :) I gonna look it up and ask if I realy need more help :)

Comment: @IngoBittersmann, could you accept the answer if it helped you?

Comment: sry first time using stackoverflow :)